# Do I need to completely delete and recreate my beanstalk app if I change requirements.txt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed the [directions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html) outlined in AWS documentation for creating an Elastic Beanstalk application, however after deploying my application via "eb start" the status was red. I checked the log files and learned that my requirements.txt file had an error in it (I used "=" where I should have used "=="). I fixed by requirements file, checked it into Git, and did a "git aws.push". This did not get my app running and when the app auto updated it gave me the same error. I figured an "eb stop" "eb start" would do the trick (maybe a full manual restart would work?) but that didn't work either. I eventually had to delete my app and recreate it to get the old requirements.txt cleared out so that the new one could be used.

Is this expected behavior? I'm new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and read through as much doc as I could however I couldn't find any footnotes describing behavior in a scenario like this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file like this:

```
# .ebexetensions/always-update-pip.config
container_commands:
  keep-pip-up2date:
    command: pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have run git aws.push and the environment has been updated, take a snapshot of your logs. In the /var/log/eb-tools.log You should see which pip requirements are being updated/installed and which requirements already exist.